# App Script - Google Sheet data from single cell to discord - error: {"content": ["Could not interpret \"{}\" as string."]}

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, discord

First time at attempting a discord bot but I have finally decided to seek assistance in this problem. The error is as per headline and I was not able to solve it. In fact when making changes indicated by similar threads the error changes from {"content": ["Could not interpret "{}" as string."]} to {"message": "400: Bad Request", "code": 0}. The purpose is to simply get the content from a single cell and send it as a message to discord. Cannot be embed as has to ping a role that will accompany the message.

```
function onEdit() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0];
var range = sheet.getRange('I2');
 range.activate();

var selection = sheet.getSelection();
var message = selection.getCurrentCell();
    

var discordUrl = "https://discord.com/api/webhooks;

`changed to var payload = {content:message} and received the new error` 
var payload = JSON.stringify({content: message});

var params = {
  method: "POST",
  payload: payload,
  muteHttpExceptions : true,
  contentType: "application/json"
};

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(discordUrl, params);

  Logger.log(response.getContentText());

}
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. It looks that there is a missing `"`on  `var discordUrl = "https://discord.com/api/webhooks;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Issue:

The return of [getCurrentCell](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/selection#getcurrentcell) is [Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range) and the `content` in the request body should be on String.

### Solution:

To get the value from a single cell, you can use [getValue](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalue). However, if the range has more than one element, it will return the value of top-left cell in the range.

Your code should look like this:

```
function onEdit() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0];
var range = sheet.getRange('I2');
var message = range.getValue(); 
    
var discordUrl = "https://discord.com/api/webhooks/XXXX";

`changed to var payload = {content:message} and received the new error` 
var payload = JSON.stringify({content: message});

var params = {
  method: "POST",
  payload: payload,
  muteHttpExceptions : true,
  contentType: "application/json"
};

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(discordUrl, params);

  Logger.log(response.getContentText());

}
```

Comment: Thank you, So just to further my enlightenment in this field because I have range.activate followed then by another selection and get value that is 2 elements which it doesn't like and it tries to return the value of top left?

Comment: It will return the value of first cell in your range. Example: I have range of A1:B1 and the values are 1,2. If I used getValue, it will return the top left element which is 1. getValue is ideal to range that has 1 cell.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you for your assistance and also the information.